# If Stellar key pairs are Ed25519, does this mean that minisign keys can be as Stellar keys?

Tags: stellar-sdk, keypair

Can I use minisign keys, which are ed25519, as unique Stellar keypairs?

https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Keypair.html
https://jedisct1.github.io/minisign/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to create minisign keys and use them as stellar keypairs.  Is this possible?